# Merging geodataframes in geopandas (CRS do not match)

Tags: pandas, gis, geopandas

I am trying to merge two geodataframes (want to see which polygon each point is in).

The following code gets me a warning first ("`CRS does not match!`")
and then an error ("`RTreeError: Coordinates must not have minimums more than maximums`").

What exactly is wrong in there? Are CRS coordinates systems? If so, why are they not loaded the same way?

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, mapping,shape
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame, read_file
#from geopandas.tools import overlay
from geopandas.tools import sjoin

print('Reading points...')
points=pd.read_csv(points_csv)
points['geometry'] = points.apply(lambda z: Point(z.Latitude, z.Longitude), axis=1)
PointsGeodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points)
print PointsGeodataframe.head()
print('Reading polygons...')
PolygonsGeodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(china_shapefile+".shp")
print PolygonsGeodataframe.head()
print('Merging GeoDataframes...')
merged=sjoin(PointsGeodataframe, PolygonsGeodataframe, how='left', op='intersects')

#merged = PointsGeodataframe.merge(PolygonsGeodataframe, left_on='iso_alpha2', right_on='ISO2', how='left')
print(merged.head(5))
```

Link to data for reproduction:
[Shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7wwmhtfivg4qvjg/AAC0Lr03SYH4XvPJledGpHxma?dl=0),
[GPS points](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8j8j6uyavi4jdnn/sample_map_data.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? (some code to make the two dataframes that reproduces the issue)

Comment: CRS is indeed a coordinate reference system. You can check it with the `.crs` attribute of the GeoDataFrame. `PolygonsGeodataframe` will have the CRS that is specified in the shapefile, while the `PointsGeodataframe` will have no CRS. If both have the same CRS, you can do `PointsGeodataframe.crs = PolygonsGeodataframe.crs`

Comment: @joris The code is a bit tricky since I don't know how to reproduce the "geometry" column that geopandas made out of the shapefile, but I've edited the question to provide a link to the shapefile, and a link to the simple csv I am using.

Comment: @joris using PointsGeodataframe.crs = PolygonsGeodataframe.crs indeed makes the warning disappear. However the error about minimums more than maximums is still there.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments on the question, you can eliminate the `CRS does not match!` warning by manually setting `PointsGeodataframe.crs = PolygonsGeodataframe.crs` (assuming the CRSs are indeed the same for both datasets).

However, that doesn't address the `RTreeError`. It's possible that you have missing lat/lon data in `points_csv` - in that case you would end up creating `Point` objects containing NaN values (i.e. `Point(nan nan)`), which go on to cause issues in `rtree`. I had a similar problem and the fix was just to filter out rows with missing coordinate data when loading in the CSV:

```
points=pd.read_csv(points_csv).dropna(subset=["Latitude", "Longitude"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add an answer here since I was recently struggling with this and couldn't find a great answer here. The [Geopandas documentation](http://geopandas.org/projections.html) has a good example for how to solve the "CRS does not match" issue.

I copied the entire code chunk from the documentation below, but the most relevant line is this one, where the `to_crs()` method is used to reproject a geodataframe. You can call `mygeodataframe.crs` to find the CRS of each dataframe, and then `to_crs()` to reproject one to match the other, like so:

```
world = world.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3395'})
```

Simply setting `PointsGeodataframe.crs = PolygonsGeodataframe.crs` will stop the error from being thrown, but will not correctly reproject the geometry.

Full documentation code for reference:

```
# load example data
In [1]: world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

# Check original projection
# (it's Platte Carre! x-y are long and lat)
In [2]: world.crs
Out[2]: {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

# Visualize
In [3]: ax = world.plot()

In [4]: ax.set_title("WGS84 (lat/lon)");

# Reproject to Mercator (after dropping Antartica)
In [5]: world = world[(world.name != "Antarctica") & (world.name != "Fr. S. Antarctic Lands")]

In [6]: world = world.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3395'}) # world.to_crs(epsg=3395) would also work

In [7]: ax = world.plot()

In [8]: ax.set_title("Mercator");
```